# Add a link in webpage that links to a Windows Explorer window?

Tags: windows-explorer

My client wants to add a link to a webpage. When the link is clicked, Windows Explorer will open and go to an FTP site (e.g., ftp://ftp.domain.com/). I tried the following HTML

```
<a href="ftp://ftp.domain.com/">ftp://ftp.domain.com/</a>
```

Unfortunately, this will open the FTP site in the web browser which supports downloading only but not uploading.

I prefer a cross-browser solution, but an IE-only solution would be fine as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to upload specify credentials that have write permission:

```
<a href="ftp://username:password@ftp.domain.com/">ftp://ftp.domain.com/</a>
```

But i'm not sure IE accepts that.

Comment: @NullUserException and Jeroen - With your solution, the FTP site is opened in IE which does NOT support uploading files. My client wants it to open in Windows Explorer because it supports uploading.

Comment: it didnt show the username/password combination so edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure anonymous users can actually upload files?
You can supply a username/password combination by using:

```
<a href="ftp://username:password@domain.com">
```

If that fails, there's nothing you can do short of writing a web-based FTP client.

*EDIT:* AFAIK What program is used to open a protocol (FTP in this case) is defined by the browser and that's something you can't change.

Comment: then how to change the program for opening a protocol in browsers?